# Spring Integration UDP server for clients behind NAT

Tags: java, udp, spring-integration, nat

I tried to implement UDP server using Spring Integration like it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19331926/5533288) but when clients operate behind NAT they will never receive responses from server. It's because server should send response datagrams from the same port as UDP adapter port (check UDP via NAT explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/456838)).

How can I achieve proper UDP communication with clients behind NAT using Spring Integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in those threads; there are not currently any gateways for UDP, only channel adapters. Gateways are used for two-way integration.

There has just not been any demand over the years for UDP gateways.

We did [make some changes](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2776) to facilitate users replying to incoming messages (by adding the sending port as as header).

This will allow you do construct a `DatagramPacket` (perhaps using the SI `DatagramPacketMessageMapper`) and send it to the originating system using your own code.

If you want us to reconsider providing UDP gateways, make a comment on the [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-1809). Even better, consider [contributing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

**EDIT**

For asynchronous sends you don't need a gateway; buy you need to tweak the mapper and message handler which is built into the outbound adapter.

Change the `DatagramPacketMessageMapper` [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/udp/DatagramPacketMessageMapper.java#L132) to set the `socketAddress` using message headers; and add an option to the `UnicastSendingMessageHandler` so that it doesn't unconditionally set the `destinationAddress` [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/udp/UnicastSendingMessageHandler.java#L261).

You can do this by subclassing the handler and overriding the `send()` method.

You can then wire your customized message handler into a `<service-activator/>` using the `ref` attribute.

Comment: Wow! Thank You Gary for very fast answer! I would like to contribute very much. Or try at least. I read the general rules for contributors but could You point me some kind of Gateway example I could base on? Or give me some kind of fast advice where should I look in existing SI code?
I must be able to send responses from the same port as `udp-inbound-channel-adapter` port. I also have to be able to send datagrams from server to clients asynchronously.

Comment: Thank You Gary. Hopefully soon I'll try to figure out something.

Comment: Gary - I just added JIRA issue with my final requirements: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3883
Pull-request with my proposal should be delivered soon.

Comment: Solution delivered: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1624
Thanks :)